# Obtaining pressure force in the Poiseuille's equation derivation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

While deriving the poiseuille's equation for the flow of a liquid in a cylindrical pipe, one considers the force-balancing equation of viscosity and pressure forces across a pipe of radius $R$ and length $l$, and cross-sectional area $A$;

$$(\Delta P)A = -(\eta 2\pi Rl)\frac{dv}{dr} $$
$$(\Delta P)\pi R^2 = -(\eta 2\pi Rl)\frac{dv}{dr}$$

How can you use $\pi R^2$ for the area, when you're considering a cylindrical element through which the liquid flows? Shouldn't it be $2\pi R(dr$)?

Comment: What is x supposed to be in your equations?  Shouldn't it be r?

Comment: Right. Editing that, sorry.

Comment: Hint : What does the LHS of the equation represent? ie What is $(\Delta P)A$ doing?

Comment: Cancelling out the viscous force to maintain a uniform velocity for each thin fluid layer.

Comment: Don't you called $A$ the cross section? So it is $\pi R^2$

Comment: But I'm looking at a thin cylindrical shell, and integrating the stuff happening on it to get the whole thing.